# Bucle con phpPgAdmin

Tags: php, postgresql

Inicio sesión en el panel y cuando hago click en cualquiera de los botones vuelve al login, inicio sesión otra vez, y vuelve a hacer lo mismo

El cliente y servidor esta distribuido en dos maquinas, en la misma red y con los puertos abiertos correctamente (80,443,5432)

¿Donde esta el fallo?

Características cliente:

```
CentOS Linux 7
php-fpm-7.2
nginx-1.16.1
phpPgAdmin-5.6
```

Caracteristicas servidor:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
postgresql 10
```

Configuración postgressql:
fichero postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'                                  
port = 5432                             
max_connections = 100                   
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'
```

Fichero pg_hba.conf

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0             md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::0/0                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

Comment: Salió algún error en el log de php?

Comment: No, acabo de mirar en los logs y no aparece nada (he mirado en el log de php-fpm)